# View external code in Lazarus IDE

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

Is there a way to view external code (for example the pascal source code for the writeln function) in the Lazarus IDE? I'm am curious to see if this is possible in the Lazarus IDE. (I know I can just check the free pascal documentation).
Using the call stack shows the assembler code. (I'd like the high level pascal language instead.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writeln is not a function that you can find back in the IDE.

Such a call is converted to a sequence of calls to internal procedures (mostly from fpcsrc/rtl/inc/text.inc  ).

Comment: Writeln and some other functions (e.g. `Ord`, `Chr`, `Read`, `Readln`, `New`, `Dispose`, `Succ`, `SetLength`, `Copy`, `Inc`, `Dec`, etc.) are so-called "compiler magic" functions/procedures. They are recognized by the compiler and, depending on their parameters, translated to different function calls or directly into machine code. These days, such "magic" functions are also called "intrinsics". Usually, they are functions that can operate on a range of different types.

Comment: A fairly complete list can be found in rtl/inc/system.fpd which declares them for documentation tool purposes.( http://svn.freepascal.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/rtl/inc/system.fpd?revision=33194&view=markup )